# Double clicking Netbeans executes an empty jframe instead

Tags: java, netbeans

I use Netbeans 7.1.2 IDE for java swing applications, but when i double click on Netbeans ide icon, an empty jframe is executed instead of IDE. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Why not try installing the current version?

Answer (score 0):

i reinstalled the IDE and restarted my machine and it got fine.